# Can Coderbyte challenges be posted here?

Tags: discussion, policy

Recently the challenge [Word with greatest repeat of letters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53424/20469) was posted. The OP said that it was inspired by a question on Stack Overflow, in which the user sought assistance with a solution to a Coderbyte challenge (specifically Letter Count I). The challenge posed here amounts to a reproduction of the Coderbyte challenge, since it asks the question that the SO post was trying to solve.

I wasn't able to find any copyright information about Coderbyte challenges. How should such posts here be handled?

Comment: I've asked for input from Coderbyte using their "Contact" form. Awaiting response.

Comment: @Geobits Awesome, thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I used the "Contact" form on the Coderbyte site to ask. The response I got within minutes was:

> Hi Geobits,
>
> Feel free to post challenges you see on Coderbyte, either paraphrased
>   or copy-pasted, in other places such as stack overflow, stack
>   exchange, etc. :)

This was from [Daniel Borowski.](http://danielborowski.com/)

I'm guessing that this is as clear a "yes" as possible, but my personal opinion is that posts should still be attributed with a link.

Comment: I love that you go by Geobits even when communicating with non-SE parties.

Comment: Well I was using it before SE, so it only seems natural at this point ;)

Comment: Agreed with last paragraph by Geobits. Adding my 2 cents: I think it should go without saying, if you use a content, it MUST be attributted, more so if you are reposting. Otherwise it is  plagiarism. Also, sites offer content in exchange for traffic. Don't steal traffic from others, generate more traffic in between.